# C# HttpClient Post String Array with Other Parameters

Tags: c#, post, httpclient, paramarray

I am writing a C# api client and for most of the post requests I used FormUrlEncodedContent to post the data.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email));
keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password));

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);
```

But now I need to post a string array as one parameter. Some thing like below.

```
string[] arr2 = { "dir1", "dir2"};
```

How can I send this array along with other string parameters using c# HttpClient.

Comment: Why do you use a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` instead of a [Dictionary<string, string>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @Ksv3n I have to post a string array, not a string value.

Comment: Is using JSON a possibility?

Comment: Will keyValues.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("directories", arr2.ToString() )); will work?

Comment: If you use JSON, you can simply serialize any data structure into a string represented in a JSON format.

Answer (score 20):

I ran into the same issue where I had to add both some regular String parameters and a string array to a Http POST Request body.

To do this you have to do something similar to the example below (Assuming the array you want to add is an array of strings named `dirArray` ):

```
//Create List of KeyValuePairs
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> bodyProperties = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

//Add 'single' parameters
bodyProperties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email));
bodyProperties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password));

//Loop over String array and add all instances to our bodyPoperties
foreach (var dir in dirArray)
{
    bodyProperties.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("dirs[]", dir));
}

//convert your bodyProperties to an object of FormUrlEncodedContent
var dataContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(bodyProperties.ToArray());
```

Comment: I did this using ExpandoObject and serialized into a json.